# Using Polya's Theorem to check positivity of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, simplex

I wish to check if a homogeneous polynomial of total degree 4 is positive definite. The polynomial is of the form $$P(u,v,x,y) = \sum_i\alpha_iu^{i_1}v^{i_2}x^{i_3}y^{i_4}$$ with $0 \le i_j \le 2$, and $\vec u = (u,v) \in \mathbb R^2, \vec x = (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. By Polya's Theorem, if $P$ is positive then we know there exists $N$ such that $$(u+v+x+y)^N P(u,v,x,y) \ge 0$$ if $u+v+x+y = 1$ on the positive simplex in $\mathbb R^4$. However is it also true that there exists $N_1, N_2$ such that $$(u+v)^{N_1}(x+y)^{N_2}P(u,v,x,y) \ge0$$ for $u+v = 1$ and $x+y = 1$? Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial  I found a 2000 article by Bruce Resnick and Victoria Powers that gives an explicit bound for when your $N$ is large enough. I do not see that Polya's theorem implies your further splitting with $N_1,N_2,$ but I found plenty of work on polytopes other than Polya's standard positive simplex. I suggest running numerical experiments with your $P$ and $N_1, N_2$ of large but manageable size, as this seems too good to be true.

Comment: You might get somewhere with Handelman's Theorem

Answer (score 3):

Polya's theorem actually says that if $P(x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n})$ is homogeneous and positive on $\Delta_{n}$, then there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(\sum x_{i})^{N}P(x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n})$ has positive coefficients.

Looking at your question, you can just take $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ to both be zero. Since, the non-negativity of $P$ won't change. 
For considering the sign of the coefficients of 
$$
(u+v)^{N_{1}}(x+y)^{N_{2}}P(u,v,x,y)
$$
given that $(u+v)=(x+y)=1$, we have $(u+v)^{N_{1}}(x+y)^{N_{2}}P(u,v,x,y)=P(u,v,x,y)$, and so there is no reason for the coefficients to change sign (of course, I could be wrong).

If you want to try and prove/disprove this rigorously, I would recommend looking at http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611972290.ch9, specifically, look at Quillen's Theorem and his proof of Polya's Theorem using Quillen's. It might be helpful to switch to $\mathbb{C}$.